# How do I change the default font of Sticky Notes?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, sticky-notes

How can the default font be changed for the Windows 7 [Sticky Notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_notes) application? I can't stand that [faux](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faux#Adjective) handwriting font it uses.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a .reg file you can just double-click that will change the Segoe fonts to the Consolas within the registry. Created and tested working on Windows 8.1 Preview

[stickynote_font_fix.reg](https://gist.github.com/kfatehi/6513c818766b90ce3171/raw/bd8c2d48264a6c5e9d4e3acc9d7260c4a26c44c1/stickynote_font_fix.reg)

Linked code:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe Print (TrueType)"="consola.ttf"
"Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)"="consolab.ttf"
```

Log out and the font used by the Sticky Notes app should be legible.

Comment: Probably a better option than deleting the font files but will of course render the Segoe Print font unusable system wide, which may be a problem for some.

Comment: I'm disturbed that you tried this on Windows 8.1. I guess that means that after 4 major releases of Windows (Sticky Notes appeared in Vista I think) Microsoft still haven't seen fit to allow font choice in the Sticky Notes app.

Comment: You could add mappings to that registry file that map the real Segoe Print files to different names allowing you to choose to use them elsewhere if you like.

Comment: Very useful and harmless solution! My own choice of fonts is "segoeui.ttf" and "segoeuib.ttf" for a modern and clean look.

Comment: Link appears to be broken.

Comment: What about font colour?

Comment: You sir @keyvan are awesome.

Comment: For some reason, this does not seem to work on Windows 10 Enterprise.  I tried both consola.ttf and calibri.ttf, none worked.

Answer (score 78):

There are workarounds.

If you cut-and-paste text from another program, let's say Word, to a Sticky Note, that note will take on the original fonts the text was in.

To change size, luckily there are keyboard shortcuts...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> makes the font bigger

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> makes the font smaller

There is a complete list of keyboard shortcuts available [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6281-sticky-notes-change-text-format.html).

Comment: Nice find!

Comment: I knew about this but it's changing the default font that I'm really interested in.

Comment: ctrl+mousewheel also works for this

Comment: @Jeff: Yes it does, but that seems to work globally, while the keyboard method can be used to make text of different sizes, by selecting and modifying, which is a really nice thing to have found out.

Comment: Ctrl + Mousewheel for font size ;)

Comment: Strange, after closing sticky notes it will only retain it's font size if you're using the keyboard shortcuts and not the mouse scroll.

Comment: @VitaminYes Because mouse scroll isn't font size; it's (temporary) zoom.

Comment: How come this has more votes that the [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/640301/) that actually *answers* and shows how to *change default font for sticky notes*? Plus that answer *is* super user while this is not.

Comment: -1, doesn't even attempt to answer the question. How did this get so many votes?

Answer (score 39):

I know this is an old question, but I have an answer that might be better than deleting the font, but will still render the Segoe Print font useless.
In the registry, you can change the font that Windows thinks is Segoe Print and Segoe Print Bold

1. Navigate to:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
2. First, export that key so you have a backup.
3. Find `Segoe Print (TrueType)`
4. Change the value to the file name of any other font that you wish to use that is already installed (navigate that registry key to find others).
5. Do the same for the "Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)" and match it to the Bold version of this font.
6. Then, log out and back on.

Comment: The benefit of this over just deleting Segoe Print should be the ability to select the specific font that you want to use instead of Segoe Print.

Comment: Maybe there is some trick on registry to set a default font? http://www.thewindowsclub.com/tips-to-use-format-sticky-notes-in-windows-7

Answer (score 21):

There is a workaround for the default font in sticky notes.

The default typeface for notes is Segoe Print and if you don't use this font for anything else you can delete it from your system, after which sticky notes will use MS Sans Serif as the default font.

Comment: is it possible to choose the font you'd like to use, rename it to "Segoe Print" by editing the name, buried in the font file, using a text editor, and then install that font? should work.

Comment: @Redandwhite:  Please don't say that.  "should work" is a forbidden expression.

Comment: You risk breaking apps with that that rely on that font - do not recommend you do this.

Comment: Deleting system components (even if they are just fonts) is a bad idea.

Comment: The above commenters are right. While deleting a font file is less risky than deleting other files, there is always the chance of causing problems and in general system files should not be tampered with.

Comment: Oooo haa.. Have come across the 'restart the machine' kind of solutions,  but deleting is not the right way ... :)

Comment: This is still better than caliban's answer.

Answer (score 19):

Answer by [NudeRaider](https://superuser.com/users/66712/nuderaider)

---

> > You can download a .MUI editor and modify the sticky notes mui file and
> >     change the font to whatever you want.
> >
> > "C:\Windows\System32\en-US\StikyNot.exe.mui"
>
> First of all thanks for the tip with
>   the MUI file. With it I could
>   successfully change the default font
>   the sticky notes are using. Btw. plain
>   notepad works fine for editing.
>
> To solve the access denied problem you
>   have to be administrator, and take
>   control of the file first and then add
>   full access permissions for your user
>   name.
>
> Step by step:
>   - right click the file -> properties
>   - Security tab -> advanced
>   - Owner tab -> edit
>   - click your user name -> OK
>   - Permissions tab -> change permissions
>   - add...
>   - enter your user name (or click advanced to search for it) -> OK
>   - click the top left check box (allow > full access) -> OK
>   - OK -> OK -> OK
>   that's it, now you can access the file.
>
> Then you can remove the write
>   protection but you *still* can't
>   overwrite the file because notepad
>   doesn't let you save in that folder.
>   So save the edited MUI file elsewhere
>   and copy it into the en-us folder.
>   Then restart your computer or it won't
>   take effect.
>
> Also note that the en-us folder
>   depends on your system language (e.g.
>   de-de for german), but the filename
>   itself always stays StikyNot.exe.mui.

Comment: I had to use notepad++ to edit the mui file because notepad corrupted the files I edited!

Comment: apologies for the typo in user name @NudeRaider

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the text into a [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) window and change the font there to whatever you like and then copy the text back into the note, and the font will stick.

I also found a nice freeware tool named [StickyTool](http://bitsmithy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=15#p15) that expands the functionality of the Windows 7 Sticky Notes. The current version, however, is not able to change the default font of the Sticky Notes application, but I know from one of the developers that they want to integrate that in a future version.

Comment: Some might find StickyTool useful. Personally the standard sticky notes app is perfect for me, other than the horrid font. I'm looking for a similar app I can use on my new laptop, which has Windows 7 Home Basic and therefore no Sticky Notes app.

Comment: Virus Scan reports file to be virus free http://virscan.org/report/62538dbf51fe1adaa2111b76c4aeaa89.html

Comment: Copy text into Notepad and change font there and copy back is not working

Comment: @Deqing you are right. It is *not* supposed to work, actually.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, switching to something like http://pnotes.sourceforge.net/ would be your best bet.

Comment: There are many alternative apps for notes but why should I be forced to use another app just because the developers/designers of the built-in one made a poor choice?

Comment: People always use Notepad++ instead of Notepad; I don't see how this is any different.

Comment: Once thing to remember is that many folks do not have the ability to install software on employer's machines due to "policy" so must make do with built in applications.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe no one mentioned this, but Sticky Notes is written in JavaScript. You can hack the code whatever you want.

Moreover, the fonts are adequately defined in the localization file.

%LocalAppdata%\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Notes.gadget\js\loc.js

```
var L_YELLOW_TEXT        = "Yellow";
var L_PURPLE_TEXT        = "Purple";
var L_BLUE_TEXT          = "Blue";
var L_GREEN_TEXT         = "Green";
var L_PINK_TEXT          = "Pink";
var L_WHITE_TEXT         = "White";

var L_DELETENOTE_TEXT    = "Delete";
var L_PREVIOUSNOTE_TEXT  = "Previous";
var L_NEXTNOTE_TEXT      = "Next";
var L_ADDNOTE_TEXT       = "Add";

var L_FONT_1_TEXT        = "Segoe Print";
var L_FONT_2_TEXT        = "Segoe Script";
var L_FONT_3_TEXT        = "Segoe UI";
var L_FONT_4_TEXT        = "NA";
var L_FONT_5_TEXT        = "NA";
var L_FONT_6_TEXT        = "NA";
var L_FONT_7_TEXT        = "NA";
var L_FONT_8_TEXT        = "NA";
var L_FONT_9_TEXT        = "NA";
var L_FONT_10_TEXT       = "NA";

var L_PREVIOUS_text = "Previous";
var L_NEXT_text = "Next";
```

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: That's certainly an option if you want to use Sticky Notes. I've stopped using it; not because of the font. I prefer a combination of Joplin and pen and paper these days.

Comment: @SteveCrane To be honest I still haven't found the ideal note app yet (lmao). So far Sticky Notes is a neat solution, I'm using it to jot down temporary texts and todos. I've also gone so far as to setup a sync script to view it on my Android phone.