# How to open StikyNot.exe.mui in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I want to change the font style in Sticky notes. For that I want to open StikyNot.exe.mui file. Which editor I must use to open this file in windows 7? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the default font of Sticky Notes?](http://superuser.com/questions/35589/how-do-i-change-the-default-font-of-sticky-notes)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use a resource editor like [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) or [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm), this is much safer than using a "normal" text editor (notepad). It's also possible to use an hex editor like HxD, but this requires more experience.

You need to [Take Ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) to be able to replace the file.

[image: ResHacker Screenshot]

As you see in the picture, the section you are searching for is in the 23:3080 resource. I didn't tried if this actually works, it's just how to open the file!

Answer (score 0):

plain notepad works fine for editing.

To solve the access denied problem you have to be administrator, and take control of the file first and then add full access permissions for your user name.

Step by step:
- right click the file -> properties
- Security tab -> advanced
- Owner tab -> edit
- click your user name -> OK
- Permissions tab -> change permissions
- add...
- enter your user name (or click advanced to search for it) -> OK
- click the top left check box (allow > full access) -> OK
- OK -> OK -> OK that's it, now you can access the file.

Then you can remove the write protection but you still can't overwrite the file because notepad doesn't let you save in that folder. So save the edited MUI file elsewhere and copy it into the en-us folder. Then restart your computer or it won't take effect.

Also note that the en-us folder depends on your system language (e.g. de-de for german), but the filename itself always stays StikyNot.exe.mui.