# Windows 10 Sticky Notes custom font

Tags: windows-10, fonts, sticky-notes

I deleted the Segoe font a while back, because my sticky notes were hard to read with that font. My Sticky Notes worked with another font for a while, until the default font changed to a boxy-bold-pixel-like font, which is even more annoying than Segoe one.

Is there another way to customize the font of Sticky Notes? I tried pasting directly from Word, but the font isn't copied with the text.

Comment: See my answer at: https://superuser.com/a/1808727/723998

Answer (score 3):

**Hack the registry**

Windows uses Segoe Print font as default in the sticky note.
With some modifications with that font, you can use other fonts as to change the default font in the Sticky Note.

1 Start

2 Run - type regedit

3 Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts

4 On right pane Find "Segoe Print (TrueType)" and "Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)" - double click (don't forget to change both - one by one)

Optional - you can delete other Segoe fonts - select(one click), press Del, press Yes

5 Change the value(double click on font) to the file name of any other font that you wish to use that is already installed - for "times new roman" it should be times.ttf .

6 Restart the computer.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in Windows 10. Here are my steps:

- put text into WordPad (not Word) with your preferred font
- copy/paste to Sticky Notes.

Comment: why the -1? It's a correct and fast workaround for the problem...better than modify the registry.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, they fixed the "bug"

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome third party workaround solution to customize the font for Sticky Notes and still be able to use stickies in Windows 10. It is called "Stickies" from Zhorn Software, which currently offers a choice of 14 different font styles and 5 font colors. This program is a free download.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.